# Parsing a connection string with a port

Tags: java, parsing, scala

I have the following connections string at a server:

```
val connStr = "redis://redistogo:fd578d89004321fe@tarpon.redistogo.com:10333/"
```

The redis client I have to use, doesn't have a constructor appropriate for this connection string, it has only a constructor with a host and a port separately:

```
class SomeRedisClient(val host: String, val port: Int) { ...
```

. The following code doesn't work either:

```
val url = new java.net.URL(connStr)
```

error - `java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: redis`

How do I parse this connection string to pass it to redis's constructor?

P.S. I am not allowed to pick other redis client.

Comment: Every bone in my body doesn't want to say strip off the string after the last colon and before the /, but I know that's a terrible solution.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html

Comment: @Suganthan, that's not a url, that's uri.

Answer (score 3):

Use URI

```
String connStr = "redis://redistogo:fd578d89004321fe@tarpon.redistogo.com:10333/";
URI uri = new URI(connStr);
System.out.println(uri.getScheme());
System.out.println(uri.getHost());
System.out.println(uri.getPort());

String connStrWithoutPort = connStr.replace(":" + uri.getPort(), "");
System.out.println(connStrWithoutPort);

// or a more safe version (because the user info part might contain a
// password that matches the port, e.g. 
// redis://redistogo:10333@tarpon.redistogo.com:10333/
StringBuilder withoutPort = new StringBuilder();

withoutPort.append(uri.getScheme());
withoutPort.append("://");
String userInfo = uri.getUserInfo();
if (userInfo != null) {
    withoutPort.append(userInfo);
    withoutPort.append("@");
}
withoutPort.append(uri.getHost());

String withoutPortString = withoutPort.toString();
```

Comment: how do I get the whole string `redis://redistogo:fd578d89004321fe@tarpon.redistogo.com` but the port?

Comment: I want to create a connection via socket using this uri. However, sockets' constructors doesn't accept schemeSpecificPart or userInfo? The same thing for InetAddress. Would you mind giving me your suggestion about how can I create a socket then?