# Connect to an address via Socket using a special type of URI

Tags: java, sockets, scala, url

This question comes from [Parsing a connection string with a port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20116508/parsing-a-connection-string-with-a-port)

I have a connection string like the following:

```
val connStr = "redis://redistogo:fd578d89004321fe@tarpon.redistogo.com:10333/"
```

or at least  `redis://redistogo:fd578d89004321fe@tarpon.redistogo.com` + `port`

How do I connect to this address using `java.net.Socket`? It provides a few constructors, but which of them accepts such a connection string?

Comment: how is it related to scala?

Comment: @Theolodis, java or scala.

Comment: Why do you want to connect using a socket directly? It's a Redis URL, use one of the clients at http://redis.io/clients#Java to connect...

Comment: @TassosBassoukos, because I want so.

Comment: @TassosBassoukos, no one accepts this kind of url.